# How to best convert a stack trace into HTML (using .NET - C#)

Tags: c#, .net, html

Hello is there a class that does a pretty conversion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't anything built in, but it would be fairly easy.

Just grab the [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx):

```
// Create trace from exception
var trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(exception);

// or for current code location
var trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true);
```

Once you have this, just iterate the stack frames, and format them as desired.

There would be lots of ways to format this into HTML - it really depends on how you want it to look.  The basic concept would be:

```
int frameCount = trace.Framecount;
for (int i=0;i<frameCount;++i)
{
     var frame = trace.GetFrame(i);
     // Write properties to formatted HTML, including frame.GetMethod()/frame.GetFileName(), etc.
     // The specific format is really up to you.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a new question, however I'd rather suggest using an open source nuget, e.g. https://github.com/atifaziz/StackTraceFormatter than reinvent the wheel with creating HTML from scratch.